# Недоступна переменная из другого класса

Tags: java

Не могу получить доступ к переменной из другого класса

```
public static class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener 
{ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
}
```

Переменная находится в `public static void main(String[] args)`. Я присвоил текстовому полю `JTextField` переменную. Пользователь вводит дату в текстовое поле, переменная получает эту дату. Мне нужно использовать эту переменную с датой в вышеупомянутом классе. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте отдельный класс, определите для него свойства, сделайте сеттеры-геттеры. Создайте объект этого класса, с помощью сеттера установите нужные вам значения полей переменной в JTextField. Далее с помощью геттера вытащите значение из объекта, там где это нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть сразу несколько возможностей, как Вам это реализовать.
Для начала, можно `ActionListener` не выносить в отдельный класс, а использовать его как анонимный. В результате получится вот так:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        container.add(jTextField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Click");
        container.add(jbutton);
        jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(jTextField.getText());
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Если Вы используете java 8 версии, то тогда данную конструкцию можно укоротить с помощью lambda, поскольку `ActionListener` по сути дела является функциональным интерфейсом. Выглядеть это может вот так:

```
JButton jbutton = new JButton("Click");
container.add(jbutton);
jbutton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(jTextField.getText()));
```

Ну и наконец, если Вы все-таки собираетесь писать отдельный `ActionListener`, то так или иначе Вы будете его регистрировать в кнопке, а следовательно сможете передать Вашу переменную или прямо целый элемент управления в конструктор:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        container.add(jTextField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JButton jbutton = new JButton("Click");
        container.add(jbutton);
        jbutton.addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener(jTextField));

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}

class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField jTextField;

    public ButtonActionListener(JTextField jTextField) {
        this.jTextField = jTextField;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(jTextField.getText());
    }
}
```

Надеюсь это поможет двигаться дальше.